# Magento 2 Translate modules separately?

Tags: magento2, localisation

Is it possible to keep different translate files for different modules?

I have a large file with all translation in:

```
app/i18n/magento/sv_se/sv_SE.csv
```

This doesn't work: `app/i18n/"vendor_module"/sv_se/sv_SE.csv`

Or could I put all files inside my theme directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your translations in the module directory directly so in your case it should be under `app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/sv_SE.csv`

Comment: Ok, but isn't there a risk that the translation files will be overridden when I update the module?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work

Comment: This would only work if the module was originally installed under `app/code`. If the module is under `vendor`, creating the translation file under this folder doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :
    app/i18n/sv_SE.csv

Comment: Hi, yes but I rather keep the translations in different files for different modules.